# fatal error: 'openssl/e_os2.h' file not found in pypy

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptography, pypy, pyopenssl

When I Run Command pypy -m pip install cryptography

then I have got below Errors:

cc -arch x86_64 -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -I/opt/pypy-5.0.1/include -c build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:423:10: fatal error: 'openssl/e_os2.h' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/local/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/_t/8l_tq9210xl4bzlhkspnv8br0000gn/T/pip-build-Gjhf5l/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_t/8l_tq9210xl4bzlhkspnv8br0000gn/T/pip-6_y8I9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_t/8l_tq9210xl4bzlhkspnv8br0000gn/T/pip-build-Gjhf5l/cryptography/

Comment: You are missing the openssl header file. Have you installed openssl?

Answer (score 6):

On OS X PyPy you'll need to `brew install openssl` (or port install or whatever) and then run the following command:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography
```

If you use ports modify the paths to point at the proper location.

Answer (score 0):

if you pc is mac,please configure as follows:

export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib 
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

and amazingly,it works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Cryptography requires compiling C Extensions.

Depending on the the platform you're on, you should install python-dev and gcc prior to installing cryptography:

debian: `sudo apt-get install python-dev gcc`

rhel: `sudo yum install python-devel gcc`

windows: you need to install the Python C++ Runtime (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)